# efficient comparison of list elements within a list in R

Tags: r

How to compare the elements of a list element-by-element efficiently in R? The code bellow does the job, but is quite slow.

Context: my actual problem is finding  isomorphisms between connected components of a graph. The graph has ~500k vertices and ~200k connected components. All the graph stuff can be ignored, though. I suppose a similar question is how to find the elements of a vector that are equal.

Intuition for the code bellow: successively compared each element of the list with the preceding elements (already taking into account the matches found previously)

```
g=graph.edgelist(m,directed=T)
dg <- decompose.graph(g, mode = c("weak"))    
x=1
for(i in 2:length(dg)){
  print(i)
  a=1
  for(j in unique(x[1:i-1])){
    #print(j)
    if(graph.isomorphic(dg[[i]],dg[[j]])==T){
      x[i]=j
      a=0
      break
    }
    if(a==1) x[i]=i   
    #print(dg[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing all to all is O(n^2), which is slow.

Instead, I would hash each list of vertices using `digest`, then you can use that as an identifying factor:

```
example(graph.edgelist)

require(digest)
hash <- sapply(g15, digest)
length(unique(hash))
```